# How to add array of [String] to dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, dictionary

Please find below the code for proper and correct understanding:

```
var dictUpdateTasks = [String: String]()
var arrAddSteps = [String]()

 self.dictUpdateTasks["dDay"] = self.btnAddDate.titleLabel?.text
 self.dictUpdateTasks["rem"] = self.btnRemindMe.titleLabel?.text
 self.dictUpdateTasks["steps"] = arrAddSteps
```

Now , this is the error, on line

```
"self.dictUpdateTasks["steps"] = arrAddSteps"
// Error: Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'
```

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: `var dictUpdateTasks = [String: Any]()`

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs Yes, i am not much experience in to swift, whole experience in objective c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason:**

`dictUpdateTasks` is of type `[String:String]`, i.e. it can accept values only of type `String`.

```
dictUpdateTasks["steps"] = arrAddSteps
```

But in the above code, you are trying to add `[String]` type value to `dictUpdateTasks`.

**Solution:**

Change the type of `dictUpdateTasks` from `[String: String]` to `[String: Any]`,

```
var dictUpdateTasks = [String: Any]()
```

Comment: if((self.dictUpdateTasks["dateDay"]?.isEmpty ?? true)) giving problem Value of type 'Any' has no member 'isEmpty'

Comment: You will have to cast it back to `String` or `[String]` from `Any` whenever required.

Comment: isEmpty is available for both String and Array separately. There is no common protocol that contains isEmpty. In that case, you need to cast the value to String or [String] explicitly.

Comment: @iPhone7 One question I've here is, why are you adding both String and [String] types to the Dictionary. Please explain the context.

Comment: @PGDev requirement of the task, i have to add key : values as well as key : array. Like we can do same in objective c as well

Comment: @iPhone7 If that is the case, [String:Any] is what you need. And casting you've to do explicitly.

Comment: Yes, but why can't we check for the value exist in key or not as earlier doing

Comment: @iPhone7 Because `Any` doesn't have any `isEmpty` property defined. That exists for Collection types, String etc. `Any` can be anything - Int, Double etc. So you can't call isEmpty on 'Int'. That's why you need to explicitly case the values out of `dictionary` so you can call their specific methods.

Comment: checkout the above answer by me. I faced with a similar requirement like you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like checking if the value exists or not by using `isEmpty` property of both the `String` and `[String]`, on a higher level you could create a protocol separately for that. But for this scenario I would not recommend this.

```
protocol EmptyIdentifiable {
    var isEmpty: Bool { get }
}

extension String: EmptyIdentifiable { }
extension Array: EmptyIdentifiable where Element == String { }

var dictionary = [String: EmptyIdentifiable]()
dictionary["string"] = "value"
dictionary["array"] = ["values1", "values2"]

print(dictionary["string"]?.isEmpty)
print(dictionary["array"]?.isEmpty)
```

Normal solution in this current situation would be to use casting from `Any` to `String` or `[String]`.

```
if let array = dictionary["array"] as? [String] {
    print(array, array.isEmpty)
}
if let string = dictionary["string"] as? String {
    print(string, string.isEmpty)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding to my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to create a dictionary.

**Correct syntax**

```
var dictUpdateTasks = [String: Any]()
```

You have created a dictionary with `[String: String]()` and you are assigned `String Array` **arrAddSteps** instead of String.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

Need to make your dictionary type **[String : Any]**() instead of **[String : String]**()

In your case it will accept only String type in value

```
var dictUpdateTasks = [String: Any]()
var arrAddSteps = [String]()

self.dictUpdateTasks["dDay"] = self.btnAddDate.titleLabel?.text
self.dictUpdateTasks["rem"] = self.btnRemindMe.titleLabel?.text
self.dictUpdateTasks["steps"] = arrAddSteps

print(self.dictUpdateTasks)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use key value pair to assign string to dictionary.